# Checkpoint with spark file streaming in java

Tags: java, hadoop, spark-streaming

I want to implement checkpoint with spark file streaming application to process all unprocessed files from hadoop if in any case my spark streaming application stop/terminates. I am following this : [streaming programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html), but not found JavaStreamingContextFactory. Please help me what should I do.

My Code is

```
public class StartAppWithCheckPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            
            String filePath = "hdfs://Master:9000/mmi_traffic/listenerTransaction/2020/*/*/*/"; 
            String checkpointDirectory = "hdfs://Mongo1:9000/probeAnalysis/checkpoint";
            SparkSession sparkSession = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance();

            JavaStreamingContextFactory contextFactory = new JavaStreamingContextFactory() {
                  @Override public JavaStreamingContext create() {
                      
                    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ProbeAnalysis");
                    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);  
                    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(300));
                    JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.textFileStream(filePath).cache();
                    
                    jssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory);
                    return jssc;
                  }
                };
                
            JavaStreamingContext context = JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, contextFactory);
            
            context.start();
            context.awaitTermination();
            context.close();
            sparkSession.close();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [Checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing)

For checkpointing use *stateful* transformations either `updateStateByKey` or `reduceByKeyAndWindow`. There are a plenty of examples in [spark-examples](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples) provided along with prebuild spark and spark source in git-hub. For your specific, see [JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount.java](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount.java);